# react.net & Asp.net MVC5 onClick

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

Im trying to get a onClick function to simply execute an alert function, it will just not work any help will be much appreciated. The data binding is working perfectly. Just nothing with onClick will work. I can't even call the function from my browser console. It states the function is undefined. Please see code below:

```
var TestPage = React.createClass({
showMessage: function () {
    console.log('Test Click');
},

getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        userName: this.props.username,
        userEmail: this.props.useremail,
        userMarried: this.props.usermarried,
    }
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <button id="btn-compare" onClick={this.showMessage}>{this.state.userName} please click this</button>
            <div>
                {this.state.userName}
                <br />
                {this.state.userEmail}
            </div>
            <div>
                HELLO LABEL
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

Comment: What's the exact problem? Can't seem to reproduce, check this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPvVxN

Comment: It simply just ignores the onclick and if I add ReactDOM.render(
  <TestPage />,
  document.getElementById('root')
); The build then breaks

Comment: I updated the pen, if you click the button, it clearly shows an alert: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPvVxN
Do you have any other console errros?

Comment: Could this be due to a react.net issue ? This isn't the first time this is happening to me. I will have to create a repo and share the .net project